# How to print invoices automatically when multiple attachments are named the same?

Tags: vba, outlook

My macro prints invoices automatically but when multiple attachments are named the same, it prints only the first one multiple times.

```vb
Sub LSPrint(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim oFS As FileSystemObject
    Dim sTempFolder As String
    Set oFS = New FileSystemObject

    sTempFolder = oFS.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder)

    cTmpFld = sTempFolder & "\OETMP" & Format(Now, "yyyymmddhhmmss")
    MkDir (cTmpFld)

    Dim oAtt As Attachment
    For Each oAtt In Item.Attachments
    FileName = oAtt.FileName
    FullFile = cTmpFld & "\" & FileName

    oAtt.SaveAsFile (FullFile)

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(0)
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(FullFile)
    objFolderItem.InvokeVerbEx ("print")

    Next oAtt

    If Not oFS Is Nothing Then Set oFS = Nothing
    If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then Set objFolder = Nothing
    If Not objFolderItem Is Nothing Then Set objFolderItem = Nothing
    If Not objShell Is Nothing Then Set objShell = Nothing
OError:
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

How do I print multiple attachments if they are named the same?

Possibly renaming the files and then printing those.

Comment: You can create a counter on your file naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

As you stated, created a naming convention to force unique file names among the attachments. This is done here with variable `i`

```
Dim oAtt As Attachment
Dim i as Long: i = 1

For Each oAtt In Item.Attachments
    FileName = oAtt.FileName
    FullFile = cTmpFld & "\" & FileName & i  '<-- add unique identifier
    oAtt.SaveAsFile (FullFile)

    '.... More stuff

    i = i + 1  '<-- increment to next unique identifier
Next oAtt
```

Comment: When I add these lines, it doesn’t print the attachment at all

Comment: did you verify that the files are saving under the expected names? Start from the top up. You gotta give me details to get any help. Many things happen before anything should print so start at the top and see where things stop working

Comment: How do you see it step by step? F8 seems to be not working in outlook

Answer (score 0):

*Try changing the following line*

> ```
> FileName = oAtt.FileName
> ```

*To*

> ```
> FileName = oAtt.FileName & Format(Now, " yyyymmddhhmmssms")
> ```